# About the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Tags: analysis, zeta-functions

We define the function $N(T)$ is the number of non-trivial zeros $ρ$　of the Riemann zeta function which
$0<\Im (ρ) <T$ .
Then
$$ N(T+1)-N(T)=O(\log(T)) \quad (T\to \infty) $$
I understood this property.

But I couldn't understand following claim.

For arbitrarily large T>O and all non-trivial zeros $ρ=β+iγ$ ,We get
$$\frac{1}{\log (T)}=O(|T-γ|)$$

This property is used for the proof of the explicit fomula.

Please tell me about this.

Comment: The density of zeros implies we can find a sequence $T_n\to \infty$ such that $\min_\gamma |T_n-\gamma| \ge \frac{C}{\log T_n}$. Because of the $\frac{1}{s-\rho}$ terms in the approximation of $\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)$, to keep it not too large and apply the residue theorem to $\int_{2-iT_n}^{2+iT_n} \frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(s)\frac{x^s}{s}ds$ we need such a lower bound for $\min_\rho |s-\rho|, \Im(s)=T_n$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I considered $N(T+1)-N(T)$ as only the number of zeros.Since you use the word "density",I considered this as the density. Then I Could get the sequence $T_n$. Thank you.